# Where is Juval Lowy's ServiceModelEx library for WCF?

Tags: web-services, wcf, servicemodelex

WCF is Microsoft's replacement for .Net Remoting and Web services.  It's critical to understand if you are a .NET component developer.

The best reference for WCF appears to be (by word of mouth, blogs and Amazon) Juval Lowy's "Programming WCF Services," published by O'Reilly.

This book is advertised in several places around the net as "coming with Juval Lowy's ServiceModelEx library," which is supposed to be this awesome WCF framework that extends and simplifies WCF development.  In the book itself Lowy talks about this framework a lot.

However, I can not figure out where to download said library.  If you look at his website's download [page](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11) there's tons of stuff but no ServiceModelEx.

Does he intend for his readers to re-code all of it by hand going by code samples in his book?

Anyone with any experience on this?

Yeah, this is a niche question, but I think it's an important topic and it's certainly programming related.

Comment: It's kind of sad that it's not a project of it's own, with people being able to contribute, test and maybe even ultimately integrate it (or some subset thereof) into the core of WCF. For example, the publish-subscribe framework he provides is pretty useful.

Comment: Drozzy, maybe if it had been created in 2013 instead of back in '06 or '07...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The latest version is maintained on IDesign's site here:

http://idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1887

Older version are available on the O'Reilly site.

Programming WCF Services 3rd Edition (PWSTE) Samples:
http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596805494/

Programming WCF Services 2nd Edition (PWSSE) Samples:
http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596521301/

I found this via:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521301/

and clicking on "Examples"

Download the zip file and it has all the code for ServiceModelEx. I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually it is on the web site but seems to only be part of the WCF downloads ( ie as part of a demo) not a solo download.
I downloaded the Trace Interceptor from here:
 http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#WCFEssentials 
and the source code is included.

Comment: +1 You would think the book itself would have a nice bold URL to the samples download instead of hiding it on some obscure link and calling it "PWSSE-Sources.zip".

Answer (score 1):

you can find it here:

http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#WCFEssentials

Just search for "ServiceModelEx" in your browser to jump to the right link ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the PWSTE - Sources there are four subfolders:

1. ServiceModelEx
2. ServiceModelEx (.NET 3.5)
3. ServiceModelEx(no service bus)
4. Tools

The `ServiceModelEx` is included at the source level at many sample projects under WCF Samples.
By studying Juval's code you can learn lot of good stuff.
Good bless him.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same process. But, luckily, I needed to download InProc Factory project from Idesign's site and there it was, the ServiceModelEx is bundled with InProc Factory example.

It is stored under [InProc Factory](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#WCFEssentials).

The zip file has two projects. One is InProc Factory and the other one is ServiceModelEx.
Hope this is helpful.